# SMS/Phone validation of Whatsapp/Viber not working on Cyanogenmod 7.2

Tags: cyanogenmod, whatsapp-messenger

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S (I9000) and have been using Whatsapp before with Cyanogenmod 7.1. I've tried reinstalling many times via the market and by downloading the recent .apk from whatsapp website. I stil cant get the validation to work on both programs.

I'm assuming, that cyanogen is "blocking" these apps to send a SMS/Call request to their server, because there is never an answer.

Any Ideas?

Comment: No CM doesn't block stuff unless you explicitly tell it so. I have trouble receiving some of these messages too but viber works. Samsung Chaton, and whatsapp doesn't. What country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

This is a member of the Viber R&D Team!

Viber is compatible with CM7.

Please be more specific in regards to the error message and scenario.

If anyone has any questions/suggestions for Viber, please feel free to let us know, and we will address them shortly.
Thanks,
Viber Team

Comment: Well it's simple. I installed Viber via Google Play and when i tap the "send verification SMS" button, i get the message that an SMS has been send to me. But i dont get an SMS. As this is the same "bug" as in Whatsapp im guessing that it isnt a bug from the App itself.